# How can I reset the CUDA error to success with Driver API after a trap instruction?

Tags: error-handling, cuda, cuda-driver

I have a kernel, which might call `asm("trap;")` inside kernel. But when that happens, the CUDA error code is set to launch fail, and I cannot reset it.

In CUDA Runtime API, we can use `cudaGetLastError` to get the last error and in the mean time, reset it to `cudaSuccess`.

Is there a way to do that with Driver API?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This type of error cannot be reset with the CUDA Runtime API `cudaGetLastError()` function.

There are two types of CUDA runtime errors:  "sticky" and "non-sticky".  "non-sticky" errors are those which do not corrupt the context.  For example, a `cudaMalloc` request that is asking for more than the available memory will fail, but it will not corrupt the context.  Such an error is "non-sticky".

Errors that involve unexpected termination of a CUDA kernel (including your `trap` example, also in-kernel `assert()` failures, also runtime detected execution errors such as out-of-bounds accesses) are "sticky".  You cannot clear "sticky" errors with `cudaGetLastError()`.  The only method to clear these errors in the runtime API is `cudaDeviceReset()` (which eliminates all device allocations, and wipes out the context).

The corresponding driver API function is [`cuDevicePrimaryCtxReset()`](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-driver-api/group__CUDA__PRIMARY__CTX.html#group__CUDA__PRIMARY__CTX_1g5d38802e8600340283958a117466ce12)

Note that `cudaDeviceReset()` by itself is insufficient to restore a GPU to proper functional behavior.  In order to accomplish that, the "owning" process must also terminate.  See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56329377/reset-cuda-context-after-exception/56330491#56330491).

Comment: that sounds horribe, all allocated memory lost.

Comment: Indeed.  So the takeaway/conclusion is that casual usage of `trap` isn't really a good idea.  The only time I ever use in-kernel `assert()` which is similar is when I have a catastrophic failure.